# SQLite join with select not joining as expected

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to select a handful of columns and create a view in SQLite.  Why do the following pieces of code return different values?

```
SELECT date, PCEDurableGoods FROM debtandsavings
left join (select date, FedRate FROM rates) using (date);
```

but this works

```
SELECT * FROM debtandsavings
left join rates using (date);
```

The former returns the table listed first without join but the later returns the full table joined as expected

Below is an example of data

```
date            PCEDurableGoods
2022-09-01      6.612628882215829
2022-08-01      6.581442803985115
2022-07-01      6.573571833810114
2022-06-01      6.573321162184561
2022-05-01      6.50050461361015


date            FedRate
2022-09-01      2.56
2022-08-01      2.33
2022-07-01      1.68
2022-06-01      1.21
2022-05-01      0.77
```

result from first code snippet (foobar)

```
date            PCEDurableGoods
2022-09-01      6.612628882215829
2022-08-01      6.581442803985115
2022-07-01      6.573571833810114
2022-06-01      6.573321162184561
2022-05-01      6.50050461361015
```

result from second code (expected)

```
date        PCEDurableGoods     FedRate
2022-09-01  6.61262888221583    2.56
2022-08-01  6.58144280398512    2.33
2022-07-01  6.57357183381011    1.68
2022-06-01  6.57332116218456    1.21
2022-05-01  6.50050461361015    0.77
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/e5NWr9I1

Python equivalent would be

```
out_df = pd.merge(df1[['date','PCEDurableGoods'],df2['date','FedRate'],on = 'date',how='left')
```

EDITS: I updated example data as people were confused by the dates

Comment: I can't reproduce your results: https://dbfiddle.uk/dJRqAgUx

Comment: I edited the data to make them reproducible. Your dbfiddle reproduces the problem exactly

Comment: What do you mean *problem*? The queries work as expected: https://dbfiddle.uk/zcz67drB

Comment: im a bit new to sql, why wouldn't code 1 not join?

Comment: What makes you think that it does not join?

Comment: SELECT [list of all cols] FROM table1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT [list of all cols] FROM table2 USING (date); != SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (date); why not?

Comment: In dbfiddle you can see code 1 isn't joining no?

Comment: This is a query that joins with a LEFT join the 1st table to a query of the 2nd table and returns only the columns of the 1st table. What did you expect? Take some time to read about LEFT joins: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-left-join/

Comment: what you linked to and what you said say 2 different things. In python a left join uses the left keys and finds matches in the join column and append the columns that are selected. Exactly in code snippet 2

Comment: The question is why doesn't that work in code snippet1 vs works in 2 where the 2 things it's trying to join are identical https://dbfiddle.uk/e5NWr9I1

Comment: The answer is: in the 1st query you are selecting only the 2 columns of the 1st table but in the 2nd query you are selecting the 2 columns of the 1st table and 1 column of the 2nd table (this is the result of *).

Comment: Also, why do you mention Python? This is SQL where you get what you SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two columns being selected here, yet you expect three columns.

```
SELECT date, PCEDurableGoods FROM debtandsavings
left join (select date, FedRate FROM rates) using (date);
```

If you want that third column, put it in the select

```
SELECT date, PCEDurableGoods, FedRate FROM debtandsavings
left join (select date, FedRate FROM rates) using (date);
```

It's not necessary to manually filter out columns of interest in a subquery. SQL query planners work out the best and fastest way to do this, and trying to give it clues by writing special queries can in some cases just confuse it. Just use this form. SQL will work out where and the right time to collect columns

```
SELECT date, PCEDurableGoods, FedRate
FROM debtandsavings
left join rates using (date);
```

EDIT:

SQL is declarative. You tell it what you want and it works out exactly what to do behind the scenes. Use the query plan to see what it's doing  https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html. It will filter and join in whatever order it thinks is fastest. There is no need to explicitly reduce columns in subselects etc. It will work out the fastest way

Comment: oooohhh so it goes something like: select cols from (table1 join table2), In the back end is it joining 2 full tables then selecting columns from that?

Comment: "Why would you not use the second form anyway? It's simpler." I'm dealing with economic release data so pull the release into a table and 90% of it isn't relevant in any given context.

Comment: adding a special subselect with cut down fields doesn't do anything. Databases are already smart enough to only grab the fields you want

Answer (score -1):

The first example selects `date` and `PCEDurableGoods` and returns just these two columns as requested by your query. The second example uses the wildcard and returns all columns from the join, again, as expected.

In terms of the actual rowset, the second output presented by you does not correspond to the input. 2022-05-01/2022-06-01 are not in the second table and should return NULLs in `FedRate`. This most likely means that you did not execute your queries against the provided input.

Comment: "The first example selects date and PCEDurableGoods and returns just these two columns as requested by your query." Yes I can see that in the output. Why is it not joining with part 2 of the query.
I added data